# How do I add an Instagram feed to my Big Cartel home page

Tags: instagram, bigcartel

I am trying to add a feed of my Instagram/ a hashtag to my Big Cartel homepage.
I have tried several widgets but pasting the code they generate, no feed shows up on my page. 
I know I will need my Client ID and/or Access Token.
I am using the Luna Template.

I would really appreciate any help.